# How to add "rel = nofollow" to all "a" tags?

Tags: tinymce, tinymce-5

I want to add "rel = nofollow" to all "a" tags.

```
tinymce.init({
    selector: 'textarea',
    extended_valid_elements: 'img[!src|alt],a[!href|target|width|height|title|rel=nofollow]',
    valid_elements : 'p,br,a,strong,span[style],em,ul,ol,li',
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Using the code you included above, I get the behavior you are looking for, a `rel="nofollow"` is added to `<a>` tags. Here is a Tiny Fiddle demonstration:
http://fiddle.tinymce.com/Wthaab

Do you get different results in that Fiddle?

Comment: Thank you. It worked for version 6.0.3 of TinyMCE